# What's the Japanese word for amanuensis?

Tags: word-requests

An amanuensis is a person you dictate to and he/she writes down what you dictate. An amanuensis might also copy manuscripts.

What's the Japanese word for amanuensis?

Some translation tools are giving me "アマヌンシス" as a translation. Isn't there some better word?

Comment: The word _amanuensis_ has referred to many different people of varying statuses over time. There are a number of possible corresponding names in Japanese, which didn't inherit the Latin word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「筆記者{ひっきしゃ}」 and 「書記{しょき}」 would be good choices.

http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/amanuensis

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following might be appropriate.

1. 「筆生{ひっせい}」
2. 「筆記者{ひっきしゃ}」
3. 「右筆」 or 「祐筆」(ゆうひつ)
4. 「写字生{しゃじせい}」
5. 「代筆者{だいひつしゃ}」
6. 「書記{しょき}」

---

Source Used: 新和英大辞典　第5版 ― 並装